# How to calculate probability of the following scenario?

Tags: probability

I don not have any experience with probabilities, I hope someone can help ne to answer this question:

If we have two questions **X** and **Y**. Each question has one correct answer.

In each try the correct answer of each question will be changed

before each try we makes assumptions as an answer for each question (X and Y)

n = the numbers of trials, until we get at least one correct guess

k = at least one correct guess (success)

n – k = number of failures

p = probability of success in one trial = 0.5

q = 1 – p = probability of failure in one trial = 0.5

How to calculate probability?

[My answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkW7X.jpg)

Comment: There are some severe English issues here, I suspect.  I don't blame you, but it is obstructing the proper understanding of the question.  When you say the student *makes* (not "puts") an assumption, do you mean that we can assume that Question $X$ has the answer $0$, and Question $Y$ has the answer $1$?  When the student "gets" an answer, does he come up with the answer himself/herself, or is he/she given the answer?

Comment: @Brian Tung, sorry the"English" it is not my native language.
Yes, I mean the student can assume that Question X has the answer 0, and Question Y has the answer 1?

- The student given the answe, but he/she does not know this answer belongs to which question.

Answer (score 0):

$$100\%$$
If he sees $0$, the question was $X$, if he sees $1$, the question was $Y$. If I misinterpreted the question, please clarify.

Comment: ,I have meantioned in the question that, the student puts an assumption that
the answer of first question(X), AnsX=0
and for the second question(Y), AnsY= 1, 

0 and 1 are assumptions from the student, he does not know the right answer

Comment: @SHdotCom Then what exactly is being asked here? The assumption doesn't really mean anything in this case.

Comment: after the student get the answer, he can know whether  the answer match his assumption or not

Comment: if it is possible you just tell me this senario belongs to which type of probability, and I will try to find the answer.